# find: ‘echo’: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, find, echo

It is my os info:

```
sudo uname  -a 
Linux machine 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6
 (2018-10-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Files beginning at `test` in `/tmp`.

```
ls -al  test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian9 debian9 0 Nov 16 14:43 test1
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian9 debian9 0 Nov 16 14:43 test2
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian9 debian9 0 Nov 11 18:28 test.txt
```

I want to list them with `find`.

```
find /tmp -name  "test*" -type f  -exec echo  {} \;
find: ‘echo’: Permission denied
find: ‘echo’: Permission denied
find: ‘/tmp/snap.0_anbox_tzkdA1’: Permission denied
find: ‘/tmp/systemd-private-589e0bcc99cc438d9e12d06af643af76-apache2.service-J7vefp’: Permission denied
find: ‘/tmp/systemd-private-589e0bcc99cc438d9e12d06af643af76-colord.service-xtmKpt’: Permission denied
find: ‘echo’: Permission denied
find: ‘/tmp/pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n’: Permission denied
find: ‘/tmp/systemd-private-589e0bcc99cc438d9e12d06af643af76-rtkit-daemon.service-rVBMKE’: Permission denied
find: ‘/tmp/systemd-private-589e0bcc99cc438d9e12d06af643af76-dovecot.service-zTKk5O’: Permission denied
```

Why are so many `find: ‘echo’: Permission denied`?
It is no use to run with `root`

```
debian9@hwy:/tmp$ su root
Password: 
root@hwy:/tmp# find /tmp -name  "test*" -type f  -exec echo  {} \;
find: ‘echo’: Permission denied
find: ‘echo’: Permission denied
find: ‘echo’: Permission denied
```

`find` command can list all files beginning with `test`.

```
find /tmp -name "test*" -type f
/tmp/test2
/tmp/test.txt
/tmp/test1
```

Why `-exec echo {} \;` can't run?

Nothing wrong or something else as output of the below command.

```
debian9@hwy:~$ sudo find /tmp  -name "test*" -type f -exec /bin/echo  "{}" \;
```

Check the permission.

```
debian9@hwy:~$ sudo ls -al  /bin/echo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root utmp 0 Nov 11 18:05 /bin/echo
```

Comment: Every file has a `r` permission,you can see the output of `ls -al test*`.

Comment: How to make it run then?

Comment: No use to run it with sudo,it encounter same error info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kamil Maciorowski pointed you in the right direction (hence my +1 for him), but it appears there is something **very** wrong with your */bin/echo* command: here is mine,

```
# ls -l echo
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35000 gen 18  2018 echo
```

and here is yours (and I quote):

```
$ sudo ls -al  /bin/echo
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root utmp 0 Nov 11 18:05 /bin/echo
```

Can you see the differences? **Your** command belongs to the *utmp* group, instead of the *root* group. **Also**, and equally importantly, its size **IS ZERO**, while it is *35000* bytes in mine.

So, to be clear: your */bin/echo* command is totally empty, and it belongs to the wrong group. This clearly indicates serious corruption of system tools. On the basis of the information provided, there is nothing else I can offer. A clean re-install might be your best option.

Comment: There must be something more. In my Debian I created an empty file with exact the same ownership and permissions as the OP's `/bin/echo`. It executes successfully (mimics `true`). A clean re-install may indeed be the best option.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` is a builtin in many shells, so when you use it on a daily basis it just works. However `find … -exec echo … \;` uses an external executable like `/bin/echo`.

`find: ‘echo’: Permission denied` means there's something wrong with permissions of the executable. It may be your `$PATH` leads you to some "wrong" `echo` or permissions of the "right" `echo` are wrong. I'm assuming the latter.

1. Locate the executable; `whereis echo` works on many systems.
2. Check its permissions, like with `ls -l /bin/echo`.
3. Fix the permissions with `sudo chmod …`. In my Debian they are `rwxr-xr-x` (`755`). Example command: `sudo chmod 755 /bin/echo`.

Comment: Nothing wrong or something else as output of the below command.

Comment: sudo find /tmp  -name "test*" -type f -exec /bin/echo  "{}" \;

Comment: @scrapy How about if you run it without `sudo` but still with `/bin/echo`?

Comment: Pls read my answer too, perhaps you have something to add? Four eyes see better than just two.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `-exec echo`, in `find` you can use `-print` (or `-ls` if you want more info). In other words:

```
find $dir -print
```

and

```
find $dir -exec echo {} \;
```

have the same output. This is even the default, if you don't specify a `-exec`

```
find $dir -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: A subtlety: the code after the OP says "`find` command can list all files beginning with `test`" suggests they know. While `-exec echo {} \;` is not really useful, it *should* work. I read it as a basic example of `-exec echo … \;` which *in general* fails for the OP.